# Toggle property by toggling checkbox Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, vuejs2, toggle, conditional-rendering

Sorry in advance if I'm explaining this poorly, I'm a bit of novice at this.

If I have an array that contains multiple objects similar to below, how in Vue do I unselect/select a checkbox in a modal to toggle the value of the `visible` property based on it's name?  I just want to show items that have a visible of true.

Currently, I have a modal popup that displays the name property for each object along with a checkbox.  When I uncheck/check the textbox beside one or multiple of the names, I would like the list I have to update, based on the `visibility`.

I'm picturing the logic to be; *if checkbox unchecked, set visibility to false*

The code below is basically an outline to what I'm trying to explain, I know it's not syntax perfect, it's more of a visual guide to try and show what I'm asking.

Again, sorry if I'm explaining this poorly.

Thanks so much for any help

```
<!-- this would be in my modal -->
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox"
               value="usd" />
        <label for="usd">USD</label>
    </div>
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox"
               value="cad"/>
        <label for="cad">CAD</label>
    </div>
<!-- End modal -->

<section v-for="loop through MyArray" v-show="myArray.visible">
  <div>{{name}}</div>
  <div>{{value}}</div>
  <div>{{another}}</div>
  <div>{{high}}</div>
  <div>{{low}}</div>
</section>

    myArray[
            {
             name:"USD",
             value: 0.75,
             another: 0,
             high: 0,
             low: 0,
             visible:true},
            {
             name:"CAD",
             value: 1.75,
             another: 0,
             high: 0,
             low: 0,
             visible:true},
           ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to simulate a solution to fit to your case, the card in below represents a modal and when check/uncheck the checkbox the value in your table would be changed, you also hide/show the item according to its `visibility` state like :

```
   <div class="flex" v-if="item.visible">...</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
     myArray:[
            {
             name:"USD",
             value: 0.75,
             another: 0,
             high: 0,
             low: 0,
             visible:true},
            {
             name:"CAD",
             value: 1.75,
             another: 0,
             high: 0,
             low: 0,
             visible:true},
           ],
           selectedItem:{visible:false}
     
     }
  },
 methods:{
       setVisible(){
    
      this.myArray= this.myArray.filter((item)=>{
        if(item.name===this.selectedItem.name){
       item.visible=this.selectedItem.visible;
       return item;
        }else{ return item}
       
       })
       }
  }
  
  });
```

```css
.flex{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;
padding:10px;
}

.mymodal{
padding:50px;
box-shadow:1px 1px 4px #555;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

   <div id="app" class="container">
     <section v-for="item in myArray" >
        <div class="flex">
          <div>{{item.name}}</div>
          <div>{{item.value}}</div>
          <div>{{item.another}}</div>
          <div>{{item.high}}</div>
          <div>{{item.low}}</div>
           <div>{{item.visible}}</div>
          <div><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="selectedItem=item"> Show details</button></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    

    <div class="mymodal" v-if="selectedItem.visible">
        <input type="checkbox"
               v-model="selectedItem.visible" @change="setVisible">
        <label for="cad">{{selectedItem.name}}</label>
    </div>
    </div>
```